# AnyDesk MFA not working on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: anydesk

i have two laptops with AnyDesk installed on top of Ubuntu 22.04.
On none of these can i get MFA to work with AnyDesk - when enabling it and inserting the code, "Enable" button remains greyed out.

I have tried both Google Authenticator and MS Authenticator - none of these works.

AnyDesk version is 6.2.1.
Tried with version 6.1.1 - the same behaviour.

On the contrast, on an older laptop with Ubuntu 20.04 - MFA is working fine.

Has anyone faced simmilar issues? AnyDesk MFA not compatible with Ubuntu 22.04?

Thank you very much for any help i can get!

Regards,
Veljko